# Background check and contractor in a company

Tags: job-offer, background-check, contractors

I am currently doing a background check as part of my onboarding process with a large investment bank in the UK. On my resume I put just the name of company A but I was an external employee. I was a contractor from a company B.

Can the company who I have received the offer from rescind the offer from omitting that?

Thanks! 
Regards,

Comment: It is not clear what you ask. You are saying that you swapped your actual roles you had on companies A and B?

Answer (score 1):

> Can the company who I have received the offer from rescind the offer from omitting that?

If they want or consider it, yes they can.

It is not clear yet what exact mistake you made in your resume, but whatever it were, I suggest you contact the company and tell them that you noticed some errors in your resume and send them the correct version (if you still are interested in the role, of course).

This you can do in an email to the contact you have on the company. I suggest you do it ASAP so the fallout is minimal.

Comment: +1: You can say, "I need to clarify something .. I worked for A and was contracted to them through B"